# Get job log files of repository using Travis CI API

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I am currently looking for ways to obtain all job log files(such as https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/6073028/log.txt) from public repositories (such as apache/commons-math) in Travis CI using Travis CI API.

I would like to know if it is possible, and how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script and inside it make an API call , such as :

**get-logs.sh**

```
echo "Getting logs job from ${TRAVIS_JOB_ID}"

REQUEST_RESULT=$(curl -s -X GET \
-H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
-H "Accept: text/plain" \
-H "Authorization: token ${TOKEN}" \
https://api.travis-ci.org/api/job/${TRAVIS_JOB_ID}/log)

echo " * request result:"
echo "${REQUEST_RESULT}"
```

then call the script later: `sh get-logs.sh > travisLogs.log`

`${TOKEN}` is the token you have for your travis repository. https://blog.travis-ci.com/2013-01-28-token-token-token

`${TRAVIS_JOB_ID}` the id of the job, this is a travis variable too, so if this is inside a `.travis.yml` it will get the current job Id.

Ref: https://developer.travis-ci.org/resource/log#Log